# C# MVC: подтверждение удаления элемента в представлении

Tags: c#, mvc, controller

Я хочу сделать "подтверждение удаление", с помощью двух контроллеров и представлений:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var client = new ClientBaseRepo().GetClientFromList(id);
    return View("Delete", client);
}
```

Вызывается представление с текстом подтверждения удаления (обрезал HTML-теги):

```
 @model mvc_CLientBase1.Models.Client
 <h3>Подтверждаете удаление клиента?</h3>
    <div>
        <h4>Client</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fio)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Fio)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegDate)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RegDate)
            </dd>

        </dl>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteClient", "Clients")) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-actions no-color">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Тут я вызываю действие `DeleteClient` с контроллера `Clients`:

```
       /// <summary>
        /// Клиент успешно удален
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteClient(Client client)
        {
//..............

            return View("Index", list);
        }
```

**ВОПРОС: у меня в DeleteClient вместо объекта `client` передается null!**
Подскажите, как правильно передать в контроллер подтверждение удаления?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что у Вас модель не передаётся в контроллер. Естественно, что в его метод действия приходит `null`.

Есть один способ решить эту проблему. Вам нужно поместить в форму вызов метода `EditorForModel`. Он сгенерирует разметку так, что модель будет корректно передана в контроллер.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteClient", "Clients"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

При желании, то, что сгенерировал `EditorForModel` можно спрятать обернув в `span` или `div` с `display:none`.

Однако всё это не самый продуктивный подход, т.к. увеличивает объём страницы и объём данных передаваемых по сети (в обе стороны).

Гораздо лучше оправлять `id` и выполнять удаление в соответствии с `id`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteClient(int id)
{
    // Здесь производим удаление
    return View("Index", list);
}
```

Даже если Вы используете Entity Framework или LinqToSQL или т.п., выполнить удаление можно и зная `id`. Для этого нет смысла передавать по по сети объект сущности целиком.